# I can't select a node in my JStree after an .ajax load in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

So I have my JStree built in a `<div id="navtree">`, and when a node is selected I load some content via the .ajax() method into another `<div id="tabs">` elsewhere on the page:

```
$("#navtree")
  .jstree({
  "core" : { "animation" : 0 },
  "themes" : { "theme" : "classic", "dots" : true, "icons" : false },
  "ui" : { "select_limit" : 1 },
  "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui" ]
})

.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
  data.inst.toggle_node(data.rslt.obj);
  $("#main").css("display","none");
  var identifier = $.trim(data.rslt.obj.children("a").text());
  $.ajax({
    data : {target : identifier},
    type : "POST",
    url : data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href"),
    success : function(response) {
      $("#tabs").html(response);
      $("#tabs").tabs();
      $("#main").css("display","inline");
    }
  });
  $("#searchinput").val("") .focus();
  return false;
});
```

This all works beautifully.

Included in this newly-loaded content are some `<a class="searchlink">` tags that, when clicked, I want to programatically select a node back in my jstree.

Using the .on() method I can fire an alert when I click on those `<a class="searchlink">` tags:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.searchlink", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $nodeid = "#" + $(this).text().replace(/\./g, "_");
  alert($nodeid);
  $("#navtree").jstree("select_node", $nodeid);
  //$(nodeid).trigger("select_node.jstree");
});
```

Because .on() propagates to all future elements added to the page, the alert() shows me the correct id for the node I want to select.

However, no matter how I try to do it (and I've tried everything I can think of) I can't get it to fire the "select_node" event on the node in the existing jstree, and I suspect it has something to do with the fact that these `<a class="searchlink">` tags were added to the page via the .ajax() call long after the jstree was instantiated.

NEW INFO:

Firefox web developer console shows me the error "$("#navtree").jstree is not a function" every time I click on an `<a class="searchlink">` that was loaded via .ajax().

Comment: If the alert is working, the delegated binding function is working. In other words, it's not `a.searchlink` being added by Ajax. That only leaves the $nodeid declaration or the `.jstree` line.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why I thought maybe the .ajax() call is somehow changing my scope or namespace or something, such that my jstree is no longer selectable.  The .jstree syntax should be correct, because I've tested it with an element back in the same div as the jstree and not loaded via .ajax(), and it behaves as expected.  In fact, the only real difference between what I'm trying to do and the [first demo on the Core documentation page](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#demos) is the .ajax() call.

Comment: Be aware that your variable named "$nodeid" is a string, not a jQuery object...  The commented line $(nodeid) will fail because the variable name is $nodeid, not nodeid...  I mention this because the variable naming is confusing if you are thinking it is a jQuery object.

Comment: You are correct, that is a typo.  I didn't really mean to leave that line in there, anyway.  I can't get that .trigger() method to work either, because I don't know what to pass as the data parameter for the bound function.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error "$("#sometree").jstree is not a function" a while back when I was trying to populate a div on the same screen on click of a node on the tree. Turned out that the page which got loaded onto the div was loading jquery again which was causing this weird issue. Check if the content you load via ajax has a directive to load jquery again.